# Why is it that differentiating x would give me 1 when 1 appears to be multiplied by 0

Tags: calculus

If I am to differentiate $x$, I would do

$$\frac{d}{dx} = nx^{n-1}$$

and $n$ is $1$ so I would get

$$\frac{d}{dx} = 1(0)$$

and so $0$. But this isn't so and I would end up with $1$. Why is it that I don't get $0$ as $1$ is multiplied by $0$?

Comment: What is $x^0$?${}$

Comment: Keep in mind the importance of order: differentiating before evaluation will usually not equal evaluating before differentiation.  The latter would have us differentiating a constant, so always gives zero regardless of where the evaluation was done.  The former is more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You would get $\frac{d}{dx}x = 1\cdot x^0$, and $x^0=1$, so you get $\frac{d}{dx}x = 1\cdot 1 = 1$.

Your calculation is allright to the point where you got $$n\cdot x^{n-1}$$

but then you seem to have made a mistake either in plugging in $n=1$ or in evaluating $x^0$ (which is equal to $1$, not $0$).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've made the following calculation

*x*<sup>n-1</sup> for n=1
*x*<sup>1-1</sup> = *x*<sup>0</sup> = 0
But *x*<sup>0</sup> ≠ 0, *x*<sup>0</sup> = 1

*Now* try the derivative.